# Can a Timer from a open form interupt code on other open form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, timer

I know that the description is a bit vague therefore a better description.

I have 1 open Form1 with a timer on it that updates every minute.

But I am at work on another form2 and Form1 is open can it be that if I on form2 press a button to send data to SQL (insert into statement) the timer interupts the code and so the data is not saved in SQLserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The WinForm framework operates on a single thread.  Therefore, if Form2 is currently executing a database command, the UI thread will be busy until that command is complete.  No other UI activity will be processed until the thread is free to do so.  You could use a `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` instead, since those operate on a separate thread, however, if the purpose of the timer is to modify the UI in some way, such as showing status or progress, then the changes to the UI will not occur until the UI thread is free, anyway.  The best way to handle these kinds of situations it to, instead, do the time-intensive work on a separate thread so that the UI thread is free while the work is being done.  The easiest way to do that in a form is by using the `BackgroundWorker` component.  It's a component, so you can drag one onto your form from the form designer tool box.